# Fragment inflating 5 diffrent but similar layouts, I want to connect these 5 inflated layouts/views with the belonging activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager, layout-inflater

I want to implement 5 Weekdays(Monday-Friday) as Fragments in a FragmentContainer.
In the class ArrayListFragment on function onCreateView(...)
I inflate 5 diffrent layouts. One for each weekday.
Now I have 5 Activities like ConfigureMondayActivity.class.

When I want to start those Activities they create there own Layouts of
"R.layout.configure_monday" maybe because I set on default
`setContentView(R.layout.configure_monday);` in ConfigureMondayActivity.

How can I pass the created View `v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.configure_monday, container, false);` into my ConfigureMondayActivity ??

Code of FragmentContainer = FragmentPagerSupport + Fragments = ArrayListFragments below:

```
public class FragmentPagerSupport extends FragmentActivity implements OnScheduleWeekPass {
static final int NUM_ITEMS = 5;
private ScheduleWeek configuredScheduleWeek = new ImplScheduleWeek();

MyAdapter mAdapter;

ViewPager mPager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager);

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Watch for button clicks.
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goto_first);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        }
    });
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goto_last);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(NUM_ITEMS - 1);
        }
    });

    //TODO Initiate configureScheduleWeek with getIntent(...) from MainActivity
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent().putExtra(MainActivity.CONFIGURED_SCHEDULE_WEEK, configuredScheduleWeek));
}

@Override
public ScheduleWeek getScheduleWeek() {
    return configuredScheduleWeek;
}

@Override
public void setScheduleWeek(ScheduleWeek scheduleWeek) {
    configuredScheduleWeek = scheduleWeek;
}

public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
}

public static class ArrayListFragment extends Fragment {
    int mNum;
    OnScheduleWeekPass scheduleWeekPasser;



    /**
     * Create a new instance of CountingFragment, providing "num"
     * as an argument.
     */
    static ArrayListFragment newInstance(int num) {
        ArrayListFragment f = new ArrayListFragment();

        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    /**
     * When creating, retrieve this instance's number from its arguments.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
    }

    /**
     * The Fragment's UI is just a simple text view showing its
     * instance number.
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ScheduleWeek configuredScheduleWeek = scheduleWeekPasser.getScheduleWeek();
        //View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container, false);
        //View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        View v = null;
        switch (mNum) {
            case 0:
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.configure_monday, container, false);
                Intent configureScheduleIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ConfigureMondayActivity.class);
                configureScheduleIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.CONFIGURED_SCHEDULE_WEEK, configuredScheduleWeek);
                startActivity(configureScheduleIntent);
                //scheduleWeekPasser.setScheduleWeek(configuredScheduleWeek);
                break;
            case 1:
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.configure_tuesday, container, false);
                break;
            case 2:
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.configure_wednesday, container, false);
                break;
            case 3:
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.configure_thursday, container, false);
                break;
            case 4:
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.configure_friday, container, false);
                break;
        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        scheduleWeekPasser = (OnScheduleWeekPass) activity;
    }
}
}
```

Code of ConfigureMondayActivity below:

```
public class ConfigureMondayActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
private String[] mondayLessonNames = new String[]{"Frei", "Frei", "Frei", "Frei", "Frei", "Frei", "Frei", "Frei", "Frei", "Frei"};
private String[] mondayTeachers = new String[]{"Frei", "Frei", "Frei", "Frei", "Frei", "Frei", "Frei", "Frei", "Frei", "Frei"};
private String[] mondayRooms = new String[]{"Frei", "Frei", "Frei", "Frei", "Frei", "Frei", "Frei", "Frei", "Frei", "Frei"};
private String[] mondayPeriods = new String[]{"wöchentlich", "wöchentlich", "wöchentlich", "wöchentlich", "wöchentlich", "wöchentlich", "wöchentlich", "wöchentlich", "wöchentlich", "wöchentlich"};

private Intent configureScheduleIntent = null;
private ScheduleWeek configuredScheduleWeek;
private TextView[] tvMondayLessonTimes = new TextView[20];
private int[] btnMondayIDs = new int[41];

private static final String CANCEL_MSG_CONFIGURE_TUESDAY = "Der Vorgang: \"Erstellen des Stundenplans am Dienstag\" wurde abgebrochen!";

private Button[] lessonNameButtons = new Button[10];
private Button[] teacherButtons = new Button[10];
private Button[] roomButtons = new Button[10];
private Button[] periodButtons = new Button[10];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.configure_monday);

    lessonNameButtons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonZeroLessonName);
    lessonNameButtons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonOneLessonName);
    lessonNameButtons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonTwoLessonName);
    lessonNameButtons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonThreeLessonName);
    lessonNameButtons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonFourLessonName);
    lessonNameButtons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonFiveLessonName);
    lessonNameButtons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonSixLessonName);
    lessonNameButtons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonSevenLessonName);
    lessonNameButtons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonEightLessonName);
    lessonNameButtons[9] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonNineLessonName);

    lessonNameButtons[0].setOnClickListener(this);
    lessonNameButtons[1].setOnClickListener(this);
    lessonNameButtons[2].setOnClickListener(this);
    lessonNameButtons[3].setOnClickListener(this);
    lessonNameButtons[4].setOnClickListener(this);
    lessonNameButtons[5].setOnClickListener(this);
    lessonNameButtons[6].setOnClickListener(this);
    lessonNameButtons[7].setOnClickListener(this);
    lessonNameButtons[8].setOnClickListener(this);
    lessonNameButtons[9].setOnClickListener(this);

    teacherButtons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonZeroTeacher);
    teacherButtons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonOneTeacher);
    teacherButtons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonTwoTeacher);
    teacherButtons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonThreeTeacher);
    teacherButtons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonFourTeacher);
    teacherButtons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonFiveTeacher);
    teacherButtons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonSixTeacher);
    teacherButtons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonSevenTeacher);
    teacherButtons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonEightTeacher);
    teacherButtons[9] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonNineTeacher);

    teacherButtons[0].setOnClickListener(this);
    teacherButtons[1].setOnClickListener(this);
    teacherButtons[2].setOnClickListener(this);
    teacherButtons[3].setOnClickListener(this);
    teacherButtons[4].setOnClickListener(this);
    teacherButtons[5].setOnClickListener(this);
    teacherButtons[6].setOnClickListener(this);
    teacherButtons[7].setOnClickListener(this);
    teacherButtons[8].setOnClickListener(this);
    teacherButtons[9].setOnClickListener(this);

    roomButtons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonZeroRoom);
    roomButtons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonOneRoom);
    roomButtons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonTwoRoom);
    roomButtons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonThreeRoom);
    roomButtons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonFourRoom);
    roomButtons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonFiveRoom);
    roomButtons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonSixRoom);
    roomButtons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonSevenRoom);
    roomButtons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonEightRoom);
    roomButtons[9] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonNineRoom);

    roomButtons[0].setOnClickListener(this);
    roomButtons[1].setOnClickListener(this);
    roomButtons[2].setOnClickListener(this);
    roomButtons[3].setOnClickListener(this);
    roomButtons[4].setOnClickListener(this);
    roomButtons[5].setOnClickListener(this);
    roomButtons[6].setOnClickListener(this);
    roomButtons[7].setOnClickListener(this);
    roomButtons[8].setOnClickListener(this);
    roomButtons[9].setOnClickListener(this);

    periodButtons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonZeroPeriod);
    periodButtons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonOnePeriod);
    periodButtons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonTwoPeriod);
    periodButtons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonThreePeriod);
    periodButtons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonFourPeriod);
    periodButtons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonFivePeriod);
    periodButtons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonSixPeriod);
    periodButtons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonSevenPeriod);
    periodButtons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonEightPeriod);
    periodButtons[9] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondayLessonNinePeriod);

    periodButtons[0].setOnClickListener(this);
    periodButtons[1].setOnClickListener(this);
    periodButtons[2].setOnClickListener(this);
    periodButtons[3].setOnClickListener(this);
    periodButtons[4].setOnClickListener(this);
    periodButtons[5].setOnClickListener(this);
    periodButtons[6].setOnClickListener(this);
    periodButtons[7].setOnClickListener(this);
    periodButtons[8].setOnClickListener(this);
    periodButtons[9].setOnClickListener(this);

    Button btnMondaySave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMondaySave);
    btnMondaySave.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnMondayIDs[0] = R.id.btnMondayLessonZeroLessonName;
    btnMondayIDs[1] = R.id.btnMondayLessonOneLessonName;
    btnMondayIDs[2] = R.id.btnMondayLessonTwoLessonName;
    btnMondayIDs[3] = R.id.btnMondayLessonThreeLessonName;
    btnMondayIDs[4] = R.id.btnMondayLessonFourLessonName;
    btnMondayIDs[5] = R.id.btnMondayLessonFiveLessonName;
    btnMondayIDs[6] = R.id.btnMondayLessonSixLessonName;
    btnMondayIDs[7] = R.id.btnMondayLessonSevenLessonName;
    btnMondayIDs[8] = R.id.btnMondayLessonEightLessonName;
    btnMondayIDs[9] = R.id.btnMondayLessonNineLessonName;
    btnMondayIDs[10] = R.id.btnMondayLessonZeroTeacher;
    btnMondayIDs[11] = R.id.btnMondayLessonOneTeacher;
    btnMondayIDs[12] = R.id.btnMondayLessonTwoTeacher;
    btnMondayIDs[13] = R.id.btnMondayLessonThreeTeacher;
    btnMondayIDs[14] = R.id.btnMondayLessonFourTeacher;
    btnMondayIDs[15] = R.id.btnMondayLessonFiveTeacher;
    btnMondayIDs[16] = R.id.btnMondayLessonSixTeacher;
    btnMondayIDs[17] = R.id.btnMondayLessonSevenTeacher;
    btnMondayIDs[18] = R.id.btnMondayLessonEightTeacher;
    btnMondayIDs[19] = R.id.btnMondayLessonNineTeacher;
    btnMondayIDs[20] = R.id.btnMondayLessonZeroRoom;
    btnMondayIDs[21] = R.id.btnMondayLessonOneRoom;
    btnMondayIDs[22] = R.id.btnMondayLessonTwoRoom;
    btnMondayIDs[23] = R.id.btnMondayLessonThreeRoom;
    btnMondayIDs[24] = R.id.btnMondayLessonFourRoom;
    btnMondayIDs[25] = R.id.btnMondayLessonFiveRoom;
    btnMondayIDs[26] = R.id.btnMondayLessonSixRoom;
    btnMondayIDs[27] = R.id.btnMondayLessonSevenRoom;
    btnMondayIDs[28] = R.id.btnMondayLessonEightRoom;
    btnMondayIDs[29] = R.id.btnMondayLessonNineRoom;
    btnMondayIDs[30] = R.id.btnMondayLessonZeroPeriod;
    btnMondayIDs[31] = R.id.btnMondayLessonOnePeriod;
    btnMondayIDs[32] = R.id.btnMondayLessonTwoPeriod;
    btnMondayIDs[33] = R.id.btnMondayLessonThreePeriod;
    btnMondayIDs[34] = R.id.btnMondayLessonFourPeriod;
    btnMondayIDs[35] = R.id.btnMondayLessonFivePeriod;
    btnMondayIDs[36] = R.id.btnMondayLessonSixPeriod;
    btnMondayIDs[37] = R.id.btnMondayLessonSevenPeriod;
    btnMondayIDs[38] = R.id.btnMondayLessonEightPeriod;
    btnMondayIDs[39] = R.id.btnMondayLessonNinePeriod;
    btnMondayIDs[40] = R.id.btnMondaySave;

    tvMondayLessonTimes[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMondayLessonZeroStart);
    tvMondayLessonTimes[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMondayLessonZeroEnd);
    tvMondayLessonTimes[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMondayLessonOneStart);
    tvMondayLessonTimes[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMondayLessonOneEnd);
    tvMondayLessonTimes[4] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMondayLessonTwoStart);
    tvMondayLessonTimes[5] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMondayLessonTwoEnd);
    tvMondayLessonTimes[6] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMondayLessonThreeStart);
    tvMondayLessonTimes[7] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMondayLessonThreeEnd);
    tvMondayLessonTimes[8] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMondayLessonFourStart);
    tvMondayLessonTimes[9] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMondayLessonFourEnd);
    tvMondayLessonTimes[10] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMondayLessonFiveStart);
    tvMondayLessonTimes[11] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMondayLessonFiveEnd);
    tvMondayLessonTimes[12] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMondayLessonSixStart);
    tvMondayLessonTimes[13] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMondayLessonSixEnd);
    tvMondayLessonTimes[14] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMondayLessonSevenStart);
    tvMondayLessonTimes[15] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMondayLessonSevenEnd);
    tvMondayLessonTimes[16] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMondayLessonEightStart);
    tvMondayLessonTimes[17] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMondayLessonEightEnd);
    tvMondayLessonTimes[18] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMondayLessonNineStart);
    tvMondayLessonTimes[19] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMondayLessonNineEnd);

    //Calculates the Start and End Times of a Lesson
    DummyConfiguration dc = new DummyConfiguration();
    Configuration configuration = dc.getConfiguration();
    Calendar lessonTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    lessonTime.setTime(configuration.getStartEarliestLesson());

    ConfigureWeekdays.calculateWeekdayLessonTimes(tvMondayLessonTimes, configuration.getBreaks(), lessonTime, configuration.getLessonDurationInMinutes());

    Intent configuredScheduleWeekIntent = getIntent();
    configuredScheduleWeek = configuredScheduleWeekIntent.getExtras().getParcelable(MainActivity.CONFIGURED_SCHEDULE_WEEK);

    if (configuredScheduleWeek != null && configuredScheduleWeek.getMondayRooms() != null &&
            configuredScheduleWeek.getMondayTeachers() != null && configuredScheduleWeek.getMondayRooms() != null &&
            configuredScheduleWeek.getMondayPeriods() != null) {
        ConfigureWeekdays.initializeScheduleWeekday(mondayLessonNames, mondayTeachers, mondayRooms, mondayPeriods,
                configuredScheduleWeek.getMondayLessonNames(), configuredScheduleWeek.getMondayTeachers(),
                configuredScheduleWeek.getMondayRooms(), configuredScheduleWeek.getMondayPeriods(),
                lessonNameButtons, teacherButtons, roomButtons, periodButtons);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (configureScheduleIntent != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mondayLessonNames.length; i++) {
            ConfigureWeekdays.checkScheduleRow(i, mondayLessonNames, mondayTeachers, mondayRooms, mondayPeriods);
        }
        configuredScheduleWeek.setMondayLessonNames(mondayLessonNames);
        configuredScheduleWeek.setMondayTeachers(mondayTeachers);
        configuredScheduleWeek.setMondayRooms(mondayRooms);
        configuredScheduleWeek.setMondayPeriods(mondayPeriods);
        configureScheduleIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.CONFIGURED_SCHEDULE_WEEK, configuredScheduleWeek);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, configureScheduleIntent);
        finish();
    } else {
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        finish();
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = ConfigureWeekdays.onWeekdayButtonsClick(v, this, btnMondayIDs);
    int rc = intent.getIntExtra(ConfigureWeekdays.REQUEST_CODE, -1);
    if (rc == -1) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("The REQUEST_CODE is -1 = Error Code");
    } else {
        startActivityForResult(intent, rc);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    ConfigureWeekdays.onWeekdayButtonsResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, this, mondayLessonNames, mondayTeachers, mondayRooms, mondayPeriods, lessonNameButtons, teacherButtons, roomButtons, periodButtons);
    configuredScheduleWeek.setMondayLessonNames(mondayLessonNames);
    configuredScheduleWeek.setMondayTeachers(mondayTeachers);
    configuredScheduleWeek.setMondayRooms(mondayRooms);
    configuredScheduleWeek.setMondayPeriods(mondayPeriods);
    configureScheduleIntent = new Intent(this, ConfigureTuesdayActivity.class);
    configureScheduleIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.CONFIGURED_SCHEDULE_WEEK, configuredScheduleWeek);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, configureScheduleIntent);
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you need to use **5** Activities and **5** Fragments, when you could use just **1** Activity and **1** (or 5, but I'd recommend **1**) Fragment?

Comment: I will get 5 different data construct of each !

Comment: MondayActivity will return an obj with 4 String[]

Comment: so TuesdayActivity-FridayActivity will do.

Comment: Again... you don't need to provide such an anti-pattern.

Comment: What does that mean ?

Comment: An anti-pattern is "a bad solution to a problem".

Comment: Is there no possibility to pass the created views to my activities ? Even if my code is bad and an anti-pattern? I may have not enough time to fix it properly :(

Comment: It will cost much time because I dont know how to aggregate my 5 activities into one so far.

Comment: Really? what does it take to implement a finite-state automaton?

Comment: I will recode my classes and try to do what you sad but I will need some days bcs Im rly slow

Comment: Take your time. I'm not in a hurry.

Comment: OK I solved it finally :)

Comment: As you suggested I now use 1 activity and 1 fragment. I guess unknowingly creating anti petterns isn`t the best thing :) I try to learn more about android and how to use it! By friends :D